# When importing products via csv I get: Entity adapter object must be an instance of Mage_ImportExport_Model_Import_Entity_Abstract

Tags: magento-1.7, import, importexport

I was having trouble with Magento assigning the first QTY amount in the CSV to every single product and ignoring the assigned qty for that product. So, I tried [this fix](http://www.logicspot.com/magento/product-import-problem-stock-update-issue/) and now am getting the following error every time I try to import a CSV that was previously working:

**Entity adapter object must be an instance of Mage_ImportExport_Model_Import_Entity_Abstract**